# apache cordova visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm having trouble getting Cordova to run properly. Can you assist me on finding a solution to solving this problem?

```
Error 2
The command ""C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform iOS --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2"" exited with code 1.
C:\Users\D\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets
115
5
BlankCordovaApp2
```

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.9.3

ANDROID_HOME is not defined

Even after restarting my system, this problem still persist. I cannot run builds for any of the emulators available.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are setting your paths incorrectly. Please ensure your system variables are set as below:

Android

```
- Ensure that you have updated the SDK API level 19 through the SDK Manager
- Set the ADT_HOME environment variable to the SDK install location (default: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)
- Add to System Path: %ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Note: **ADT_HOME** not ANDROID_HOME

Java (x86 version only)

```
- Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_55
- Add to System Path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Ant

```
- Set the ANT_HOME environment to point to the Ant folder path (C/ant-1.x.x)
- Add to System Path: %ANT_HOME%\bin
```

Reboot your machine once you make changes. Projects should build and run after that.

Note: If you were trying to debug using the iOS simulator, you will need to [set up a Mac with our remote build agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665240/visual-studio-cordova-ios-build-server-setup).

*Taken from the official documentation ([PDF](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397716))

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** We `can ensure our Environment variables using Enironment Variable Settings from Visual Studio`. Try the solution to conform the Environment Variables as mentioned in the below link

[Missing ant and "code 8" errors when building multi-device hybrid application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968686/missing-ant-and-code-8-errors-when-building-multi-device-hybrid-application-pr/25987551#25987551)

**Solution 2:**  **`Rename "ANDROID-HOME" to "ADT-HOME"`**

Answer (score 0):

Try use Visual Studio settings. Choose Tools->Options->Cross platform->C++
There you can set paths for Android SDK and NDK, JDK and Apache Ant