# Missing ant and "code 8" errors when building multi-device hybrid application project

Tags: ant, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed Multi Device Hybrid apps and when I'm building and debugging new project it showing these three errors

```
Error   1   executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
Error   2   C:\Users\User\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8    
Error   3   The command ""C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform iOS --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp2" --language "en-US"" exited with code 8.
```

But I have set all the paths and adt_home in environment variables and still it is showing this error what to do

Comment: Did you set  the ant path correctly?.

Comment: Try to run %userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\check_reqs.bat for get more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following `to check and enable all required Environment Variables` for Multi-Device Hybrid App.

**Step 1:**

```
    Go to Visual Studio -> Debug Menu -> Multi-Device Hybrid Apps -> 
Environment Variables Settings
```

**Step 2:**

```
    Select Required Environment Variable from here as mentioned in 
the attached screenshot
```

[image: Environment Variable Settings]

Comment: If this answer is resolved your problem, then accept this as Answer. This will make others to refer this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ANT_HOME path is set to correct location like `%systemdrive%\apache-ant-1.9.3` and make sure ANT is installed at location ANT_HOME is pointing. Also make sure system path is set to `%ANT_HOME%\bin`. You can download ANT from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=396869) in case it is not already installed.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to “code 8” errors when building multi-device hybrid application project. The error message you get is: Error  2   \bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8    \MDAVSCLI  1   1

This happens if you play around with the config.xml in DevStudio GUI (not textually edit the file). If you change the LaunchMode property and change it back to default value which is "singleTop", a new entry will be added to config.xml: 
   <'preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singletop" />

Just delete the entry, and your project compiles fine again. Quite a nasty bug in DevStudio