# Visual Studio Cordova iOS build server setup - vs-mda-remote step

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-cordova

I've been trying to get the remote build to work. Ive been following this guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx
and from here: 
[Visual Studio Cordova iOS build server setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665240/visual-studio-cordova-ios-build-server-setup/23667009#23667009)

but whenever I run the following command:
vs-mda-remote 
(and other commands like vs-mda-remote --buildDir xxx) 
it always errors with the following:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'Q'

at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Helen/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/lib/util.js:12:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Any help ?

I have a tick on all the prerequisites 
    Mac OS X Mavericks
    Xcode 5.1 and Xcode command line tools
    An active iOS Developer Program account with Apple, with iOS provisioning profile and signing identity configured in Xcode
    Node.js installed on the Mac

both of these run fine:
sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote
sudo npm install -g ios-sim

... but i cant get any further. What am i missing, or likely to be missing? I havnt set up my developer credentials on the Mac yet if that is the problem?

Update 2:

[image]

Thanks, 
Matt

Comment: ... "sudo npm install q"
that would be my first thought... but didnt fix it. (quite new to nodejs)

Comment: Does "npm install -g q" fix it?

Comment: I believe i tried that with the '-g' and re-ran 

sudo npm install -g q
sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote
sudo npm install -g ios-sim

Its a friends mac, so i shall double check (the '-g'). It would be a easy thing to miss after an afternoon trying to get that far.

Comment: @AdamTReineke-MSFT No, that didn't fix it. Its not the io-q its after is it?

Comment: Let me ping a colleague and see if they have any thoughts.

Comment: Recommendation I got was to try reinstalling vs-mda-remote. `sudo npm uninstall -g vs-mda-remote` then `sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote`. Also a non-global install may help if that didn't. `npm install vs-mda-remote` then run `node_modules/.bin/vs-mda-remote`. (I haven't tried these myself, my Mac was borrowed for a few days.)

Answer (score 0):

I had  similar issue when trying to run from network with firewall - q npm package fail to install.

If this is the case, configuring nmp to use proxy may help:

```
npm config set proxy http://XXXXX:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://XXXXX:8080
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm cache clean
```